Can I test sent messages in kafka testcontainer?
I'm developing a spring boot application. in a method, I create a kafka message to be sent.
In unit testing, I can check if the kafkaTemplate is called for sending message or not using mockito. But in integration tests, I could not examine produced messags, because while I use testcontainer and real kafka server, but there is no way to query or listen to testcontainer kafka server.
I'm asking is there any settings, tools, methods, or other things that allow me to check if a message has been sent and the sent message is what I expected?
Also logging the message can help me testing receivers' services with actual values

Please share your code. If you're able to produce to the container, there's no reason you cannot consume

I think you didn't get the question, question is about testing and means to TEST if specific message has been produced or not

No, normally testing is about verifying if the answer to the question is correct/expected, not if "a message has been produced"

You should still share your code... You can use a callback handler on a producer to test if the broker acknowledged the record... If you want to actually test if something exists on the broker, you'll need to consume it

Just create a consumer for the topic in which you send your messages right in the test or in the configuration and wire into into the test class. Just like this:
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
properties.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
properties.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
properties.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, UUIDDeserializer.class);
properties.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
var consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties, new UUIDDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Foo.class, objectMapper));

kafkaContainer here is an insance of org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer but you can use embedded kafka, real one or whatever you want.
Then just consume below messages you've sent:
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(List.of(topic));
ConsumerRecords<UUID, Foo> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(60));

assertEquals(1, records.count());
assertEquals(expectedFoo, records.iterator().next().value());

